# two way binding not working with table rows and cols

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 inputs, called col and row which i can change and they are related to the columns and rows of a table.

I want to see that table and edit his content, at the moment i have a v-model that updates my data with the row and columns, and need to put that in my v-for for the table so the table should get automaticly updated.

The problem is that the table is not getting updated.

This is what i have:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" min="1" v-model="table.rows" class="form-control" id="rows">
</div>
<label for="columns" class="control-label col-md-1">columns:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" min="1" v-model="table.cols" class="form-control" id="cols">
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tbody  v-for="row in table.rows">
        <tr>
            <td contenteditable="true">John</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>

data() {
    return {
        table: {
            rows: 1,
            cols: 1,
            key: "Table",
            tableStyle: 1,
        },
        insert: 1,
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you saying that changing table.rows to a new value like 3 does not cause the table to be rerendered with 3 rows?  It should if your code snipits are being properly used on the page.  If not, then please show the full code for creating the vue instance and for the html that the vue instance is binding to.

Comment: I restored the code that was accidentally removed by the last edit.

Comment: np Bert, happens :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is not updated since you did not bind the text field to any model.

you need to add an `@input` event and update the model when it fires

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody  v-for="row in table.rows">
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true" @input="updateContent($event)">John</td>
    </tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>

data() {
    return {
        table: {
            rows: 1,
            cols: 1,
            key: "Table",
            tableStyle: 1,
            text: 'Default text'
        },
        insert: 1,
    }
},
methods: {
  updateContent (evt){
    //get the text
    const text = evt.srcElement.innerText;
    //update the model
    this.table.text = text
  }
}
```

Obviously this would change it for the entire table, you can change `table.row` to be a more complex object with text, and then change the text for each row

Comment: that is not true, someone decided to edit my question and delete the part where i update the model, i couldn't decline :(

Comment: the problem was related to the fact that my input was a astring